# Вёрстка 14 колонок в макете разрешение 1360px

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть макет размер контента 1360px. И 14 колонок.
Подскажите пожалуйста как стартануть на bootstrap. Ведь в нем 12 колонок и размер контента 1170px.
За ранее спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в 4м бутстрапе для scss есть миксины для генерации сетки с нужным количеством колонок и контейнеров. в третьем небось тоже было.

Comment: че то судя по шапке там дизайн вообще независим от этих колонок (:

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap можно кастомизировать.

Для этого надо зайти на страницу https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Размер контента: ищете 'Container sizes' и меняете размеры

Количество колонок: ищете 'grid-columns' и меняете

После чего в самом низу нажимаете 'Compile and Download'